# How can I duplicate a MySQL table (including structure and indexes)?

Tags: mysql

How can I duplicate the data of MySQL table, copy old one to new one?

This is what I tried but this copies the data and the structure, but not the indexes:

```
create table {new_table} 
select * from {old_table};
```

This does not copy the data but only the structure and indexes:

```
create table {new_table} 
like {old_table};
```

Comment: as a single query, you can't. create, then `insert ... select from ...` that or dump the old table to a .sql file, edit the text to change the tablename, then load up the .sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that in two queries.

```
create table newtable
Like oldtable;
Insert newtable
Select * From oldtable;
```

Hopefully, this should work

run mysql create table by selecting another and copied the indexes automatically

Answer (score 0):

You  can create one table this command

```
CREATE TABLE newtable Like oldtable;
```

Then, to copy the data You should write :

```
INSERT INTO newtable Select * From oldtable;
```